# Java RMI timeouts (crashes)

Tags: java, timeout, rmi, crash

I'm doing a server/client program in Java using RMI. When server crashes it's not a problem, clients get a RemoteException and disconnects.

However I have problems when clients crashes. My server uses a Timer to ping all client objects every now and then, when it gets no connection to a client it will catch a RemoteException.

Then, it's supposed to remove the client object from the server (just by removing it from a list), but it's impossible because when I try to do anything with the proxy client object it will throw another RemoteException. How can I solve this problem?

```
List<User> users;
Map<User, IClient> clients;

    class PingClients extends TimerTask {
          public void run() {
              for (IClient client : clients.values())
                try {
                    client.ping();
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    //removeClient(client); GENERATES REMOTEEXCEPTION
                }
          }

     }

     public boolean removeClient(IClient c) throws RemoteException{
          User u = c.getUser();
          users.remove(u);
          clients.remove(u);

          for (IClient client : clients.values())
              client.updateUsers(users);
      }
```

Comment: Please show us how you iterate through the client proxies and delete them from the list. Using an iterator to iterate and its remove method to remove the current proxy from the list should not throw any RemoteException.

Comment: You still doesn't show us how you remove clients. What's the contents of the removeClient method?

Answer (score 2):

You get a RemoteException because when you try to remove the client (which is disconnected), you first call the getUser() method on the client, which obviously throws a RemoteException.

You should change your code to something like this :

```
  class PingClients extends TimerTask {
      public void run() {
          for (Iterator<Map.Entry<User, IClient>> it = clients.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext(); )
            Entry<User, IClient> entry = it.next();
            try {
                IClient client = entry.getValue();
                client.ping();
            } 
            catch (RemoteException e) {
                it.remove();
            }
      }
  }
```

Make sure that only one thread has access to the map at a time.

Comment: Wouldn't this throw a concurrent modification exception? After all this modifies a collection while you iterate over it.

Answer (score 1):

First line, you should use [ConcurrentMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html)  instead of a Map. This will avoid you a lot of troubles due to concurrent access to your map.

Answer (score 1):

If `IClient c` is your remote object, calling `getUser()` on it will obviously throw an exception if the client is unavailable..